# x axis with a full day in hours/quarters

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to plot out an entire day divided in quarters.

```
const height = 100,
      width = 800;

const dayInQuarters = d3.timeMinute.every(15).range(startDate, endDate);

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(dayInQuarters)
  .range([0, 700])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"))

const d3Root = document.getElementById('d3-root');

const svg = d3.select(d3Root).append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height + 20);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(20,${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);
```

What is going well here is that it automatically divides the day into 8 ticks being 3 hour slots.

But the width of the ticks are abnormally wide:

[image: Screenshot of the wide tick visually]
[image]

What I would like to be able is to contain the ticks into the 800px width.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/3h51umra/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a time scale you pass just the start and end dates as the array:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([startDate, endDate])
    .range([0, 700])
```

Therefore, your `daysInQuarters` array goes in the axis' `tickValues` method:

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"))
  .tickValues(dayInQuarters)
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
const height = 100,
  width = 800;

const startDate = new Date('2021-03-14T23:00:00Z');
const endDate = d3.timeDay.offset(startDate, 1);

const dayInQuarters = d3.timeMinute.every(15).range(startDate, endDate);

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([startDate, endDate])
  .range([0, 700])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"))
  .tickValues(dayInQuarters)

const d3Root = document.getElementById('d3-root');
const svg = d3.select(d3Root).append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height + 20);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(20,${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3-root"></div>
```

And the same code, with the ticks not overlapping:

```js
const height = 100,
  width = 1000;

const startDate = new Date('2021-03-14T23:00:00Z');
const endDate = d3.timeDay.offset(startDate, 1);

const dayInQuarters = d3.timeMinute.every(15).range(startDate, endDate);

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([startDate, endDate])
  .range([20, 980])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"))
  .tickValues(dayInQuarters)

const d3Root = document.getElementById('d3-root');
const svg = d3.select(d3Root).append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height + 20);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height-50})`)
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90, 5, 17)")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3-root"></div>
```

Finally, pay attention to the *strings* you're using: your SVG is 10020px tall, not 120.

Comment: Thanks a million. I get it now. The addition of the timeDay.offset is super, that also accomodates for daylight saving changes. For the domain I've used one more addition I just found out, `d3.extent(dayInQuarters)`. Making it even more flexible.